# Javascript : Loop through an array starting and ending at different indexs

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a very large array of objects — around 30000.

```
     randomStart = Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length )
```

I'm selecting a random range from the total length.

what I want to do is loop through the array beginning at `randomStart` and ending at `randomStart + n`.

*Note*:
This array *must* stay intact, because it's too computationally expensive to re-render the entire set.

What's the best way to go about this ? What looping paradigm should be used : `for`, `while`, etc

Comment: Sounds like a basic `for` loop.

Comment: Sure, but how to start and end at different points.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: @Dalorzo, I can't use `splice` as the note in the question says..

Comment: `splice` just provides a copy; it won't 're-render' anything. But anyway, you can easily use `for (i = randomStart; i++; i <= randomStart + n)`

Comment: @Stuart, I'm using `Three.js` so it will. Forgot to add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `var i = 0` at the beginning of your for loop, simply set it to your starting index, then instead of setting the stopping condition to `i < array.length`, set it to `i < ending_index`.

This works because you then iterate `i` through all indexes between the `start` and `end_index`, just like in a "normal" for loop you iterate from `0` to the end of the array.

Comment: Make sure that the random start is less then the array length - n, or you will go past the array end.

Comment: Yes. The normal rules still apply - if you set `start` higher than `end_index` you will loop forever.

Comment: @ForeignObject If you found this answer helpful, consider marking it as the accepted answer to the question so others can know that it worked for you.

Comment: I can't yet..hasn't been five minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to process the array in batches try this.  You will have to adjust the batch limit based on your preference.

```
function ProcessLargeArray() {
    var largeArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36];

    var batchLimit = 10;

    for (var startIndex = 0; startIndex < largeArray.length; startIndex = startIndex + batchLimit) {
        ProcessBatch(largeArray, startIndex, GetEndIndex(startIndex, batchLimit, largeArray.length));
    }

}

function GetEndIndex(startIndex, batchLimit, arrayLength) {
    var endIndex = startIndex + batchLimit;

    if (endIndex > arrayLength) {
       return arrayLength;
    }

    return endIndex;
}

function ProcessBatch(someArray, startIndex, endIndex) {
    console.log("Start Batch from " + startIndex + " to " + endIndex);
    for (var i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
       console.log(someArray[i]);
    }
    console.log("Ending Batch from " + startIndex + " to " + endIndex);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var batchSize = 2;
var randomStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - batchSize));
for (var i = randomStart; i < randomStart + batchSize ; i++) {
     ///Code here
}
```